# Add Facebook login and authentication to existing user account system

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I currently have an existing login system for my site and I would like to add the ability to users to sign up for my site through Facebook.

Here is what my user model looks like.

User Model:

- Email
- Phone
- Password
- Facebook user id
- oauth token

You can sign up the regular way by providing Email, Phone, and Password.

Or you can sign up with Facebook where you just have to authenticate with Facebook and provide your Phone Number.

I am using the [Facebook Registration plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/)  for this because I need the Phone Number field. I have set the redirect-uri to http://mysite.com/fb_process which will parse the signed_request and use the data to create a user in the my database. This part works pretty smoothly.

I am not sure how to handle letting users who have authenticated my site return to log back in with Facebook.

I'm using the Javascript SDK and then using jquery to post the Facebook user id to mysite.com/fb_login which looks up user with the corresponding Facebook user id in the database and logs that user in. It technically works, but it just doesn't seem proper or secure. You could log someone in using mysite.com/fb_login?id={facebook_user_id}. See code:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId   : 'APPID',
            channelUrl : 'http://mysite.com/channel',
            status  : true, // check login status
            cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
    });


    function fbLogin() {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) { 
          FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.', response);
            $.post('fb_login', {id:response.id})
            .done(function() {
              window.location = 'http://mysite.com/user/dashboard'
            });
          });

        } 
        else {
          console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
      });
    }

    $('#fb-login').click(fbLogin);
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Also, for user registration, I would prefer not to use the Registration plugin and would prefer the flow that I've seen in most other places where you click Sign Up with Facebook, a window pops up for authentication, then it takes you to another screen to enter the rest of the details such as Phone Number. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The first time when a user visits your site, you are saving the details of the users in your database. On completion, the user will be authorized.

Now, with the [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) or OAuth you can check if the user is authorized already. If yes, no need to save the details in dB (since authorized users details are saved in dB already) and just redirect him to the desired page.

Comment: My question is about the redirection. In order to redirect the user to the "User Panel" page for example, I must first log him in. Do I simply create a login handler such as mysite.com/fb_login?id={facebook_user_id} that I post his fb user id to? Is that secure since then people can login using their fb id if they know that handler url?

Comment: I cant understand why are you sending the id. After successful login, you can get the id of the current user using `FB.api('/me?fields=id')` at any page in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to send the id securely to my login handler. I send the signed_request rather than the raw user_id. Then I use app secret to parse the signed_request which will contain the user_id.

```
    function fbLogin() {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) { 
          FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.', response);
          });
          var signedRequest = response.authResponse.signedRequest;
          window.location = '/fb_login?signed_request=' + signedRequest;
        } 
        else {
          console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
      });
    }
```